# Accessing joined elements

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Below code works when `SELECT` is working only with `CELLS` table. However, when there is join from multiple table, below type is no more suitable.

```
PROCEDURE drawComponent(title IN VARCHAR2, tbl IN VARCHAR2, link IN VARCHAR2) IS

TYPE ref_typ IS REF CURSOR;
var_ref ref_typ;
rec CELLS%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
    OPEN var_ref FOR 'SELECT CELLS.ID as CELLID, CELLS.NUM as CELLNUM, CELLS.' || link || ' as ID, ' || tbl || '.REMOVED as REMOVED FROM CELLS LEFT OUTER JOIN ' || tbl || ' ON CELLS.' || link || ' = ' || tbl || '.ID ORDER BY CELLS.NUM';

    loop
        FETCH var_ref INTO rec;
        EXIT WHEN var_ref%NOTFOUND;
        htp.p(rec.CELLID);
    end loop;
END;
```

Question is what type I should declare `rec`?

Comment: Maybe sys_refcursor? Sorry, I am tired a bit, don't want to try and write detailed example :)

Comment: Then I have `Invalid reference to variable 'REC'` if I write `rec.CELLNUM`

Comment: Dmitry, thanks and have a good rest :)

Comment: I had checked just now on oracle 12.1 - there is no problem, code from your question works fine in both cases.

Comment: It works only if I go with below answer. Otherwise of course CELLS table does not know anything about other table fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the record type of a weak dynamic ref cursor.

So, your best bet is probably to define a custom `RECORD` based on the type of the various columns you need. Something *like* that:

```
...

TYPE rec_typ IS RECORD (
  CELLID CELLS.ID%TYPE,
  CELLNUM CELLS.NUM%TYPE,
  ID NUMBER,     -- or whatever type suits your needs
  REMOVED NUMBER  -- or whatever type suits your needs
);
rec rec_type;

...
```